# Qt + cmake. Ошибка dllimport

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake, mingw

Пытаюсь скомпилировать самый простой пример Qt + cmake в c++, но он выдает ошибки.
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "G:\\qt\\5.15.2\\mingw81_64\\lib\\cmake")

# включаем путь до папки с заголовочными файлами
include_directories("E:\\g++\\тесты\\test")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# включаем поиск библиотек с использованием find_package()
# через REQUIRED указываем, что библиотеки обязательны
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloWorld ${SOURCE_FILES})

# указываем, какие библиотеки необходимо подключить
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Gui)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

#endif // MAIN_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;
 
int MYDLL_API main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
 
    QWidget widget;
    widget.resize(640, 480);
    widget.setWindowTitle("Hello, world!!!");
 
    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(&widget);
 
    QLabel * label = new QLabel("Hello, world!!!");
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter);
    gridLayout->addWidget(label);
 
    widget.show();
 
    app.exec();
}
```

Компиляция:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET Framework

  Automatic MOC for target HelloWorld
  main.cpp
E:\g++\тесты\test\main.cpp(98,15): error C2491: main: определение dllimport функция не разрешено [E:\g++\тесты\test\bui
ld\HelloWorld.vcxproj]
```

Comment: `MYDLL_API` убирите, это же не экспортируемая функция

Comment: @user7860670 Если я убираю её, то у меня появляется ошибка:
`main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QString::~QStri
ng(void)" (__imp_??1QString@@QEAA@XZ) в функции main. [E:\g++\тесты\test\build\HelloWorld.vcxproj]
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) private: static struct QTypedAr
rayData<unsigned short> * __cdecl QString::fromAscii_helper(char const *,int)" (__imp_?fromAscii_helper . . .`

Comment: Попробуйте поменять порядок `target_link_libraries` на противоположный, чтобы Core было в конце

Comment: @user7860670 Это не помогло, попытался менять как только можно

Comment: ¿Хмм, а почему путь к библиотекам содержит `mingw81_64`, а сообщения об ошибке как от Visual C++? ¿Вы там случаем компиляторы не смешиваете?

Comment: @user7860670 Я попытался поставить другие папки из qt\\5.12.2 ( например msvc2019_64, msvc2019) но это также не помогло